# Swapping elements within a matrix rows and columns - TensorFlow scatter_nd

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I am trying to use the [scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#scatter_nd) function in TensorFlow to reorder elements within rows of a Matrix.  For example, suppose I have the code:

```
indices = tf.constant([[1],[0]])
updates = tf.constant([ [5, 6, 7, 8],
                        [1, 2, 3, 4] ])
shape = tf.constant([2, 4])
scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
$ print(scatter1) = [[1,2,3,4]
                     [5,6,7,8]]
```

This reorders the rows of the `updates` matrix.

Instead of only being able to reorder the rows, I'd like to reorder the individual elements within each row as well.  If I just have a vector (Tensor of rank 1), then this example works:

```
indices = tf.constant([[1],[0],[2],[3]])
updates = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8])
shape = tf.constant([4])
scatter2 = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
$ print(scatter2) = [6,5,7,8]
```

What I really care about is to be able to swap elements within each row in `scatter1`, as I had done in `scatter2`, but do it for each row of `scatter1`.  I've tried various combinations of `indices` but keep getting errors that the sizes are inconsistent thrown by the `scatter_nd` function.

Answer (score 1):

The following swaps the elements of each row of each row using scatter_nd

```
indices = tf.constant([[[0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 3]], 
                      [[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3]]])
updates = tf.constant([ [5, 6, 7, 8],
                        [1, 2, 3, 4] ])
shape = tf.constant([2, 4])
scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(scatter1))
```

Giving an output of:
`[[6 5 7 8]
 [2 1 3 4]]`

The locations of the coordinate in `indices` define where the values are being taken from in `updates` and the actual cordinates define where the values will be placed in `scatter1`.

This answer is a few months late but hopefully still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to swap elements in the second dimension either keeping the first dimension order or not.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


def prepare_fd(fd_indices, sd_dims):
    fd_indices = tf.expand_dims(fd_indices, 1)
    fd_indices = tf.tile(fd_indices, [1, sd_dims])
    return fd_indices

# define the updates
updates = tf.constant([[11, 12, 13, 14],
                       [21, 22, 23, 24],
                       [31, 32, 33, 34]])
sd_dims = tf.shape(updates)[1]

sd_indices = tf.constant([[1, 0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2]])
fd_indices_range = tf.range(0, limit=tf.shape(updates)[0])
fd_indices_custom = tf.constant([2, 0, 1])

# define the indices
indices1 = tf.stack((prepare_fd(fd_indices_range, sd_dims), sd_indices), axis=2)
indices2 = tf.stack((prepare_fd(fd_indices_custom, sd_dims), sd_indices), axis=2)

# define the shape
shape = tf.shape(updates)

scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices1, updates, shape)
scatter2 = tf.scatter_nd(indices2, updates, shape)

print(scatter1.eval())

# array([[12, 11, 13, 14],
#        [21, 23, 22, 24],
#        [31, 32, 34, 33]], dtype=int32)

print(scatter2.eval())

# array([[21, 23, 22, 24],
#        [31, 32, 34, 33],
#        [12, 11, 13, 14]], dtype=int32)
```

May this example help.