# tensorflow: how to interleave columns of two tensors (e.g. using tf.scatter_nd)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've read the [tf.scatter_nd documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/manip/scatter_nd) and run the example code for 1D and 3D tensors... and now I'm trying to do it for a 2D tensor.  I want to 'interleave' the columns of two tensors.  For 1D tensors, one can do this via

```
'''
We want to interleave elements of 1D tensors arr1 and arr2, where
arr1 = [10, 11, 12]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
such that
desired result = [1, 2, 10, 3, 4, 11, 5, 6, 12]
'''

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:

    updates1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    indices1 = tf.constant([[0], [1], [3], [4], [6], [7]])
    shape = tf.constant([9])
    scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices1, updates1, shape)

    updates2 = tf.constant([10,11,12])
    indices2 = tf.constant([[2], [5], [8]])
    scatter2 = tf.scatter_nd(indices2, updates2, shape)

    result = scatter1 + scatter2

    print(sess.run(result))
```

(aside: is there a *better* way to do this?  I'm all ears.)

This gives the output

`[ 1  2 10  3  4 11  5  6 12]`

Yay! that worked!

Now lets' try to extend this to 2D.

```
    '''
    We want to interleave the *columns* (not rows; rows would be easy!) of

    arr1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
    arr2 = [[10 11 12], [10 11 12], [10 11 12]]
    such that
    desired result = [[1,2,10,3,4,11,5,6,12],[1,2,10,3,4,11,5,6,12],[1,2,10,3,4,11,5,6,12]]
    '''

    updates1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]])
    indices1 = tf.constant([[0], [1], [3], [4], [6], [7]])
    shape = tf.constant([3, 9])
    scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices1, updates1, shape)
```

This gives the error
`ValueError: The outer 1 dimensions of indices.shape=[6,1] must match the outer 1
dimensions of updates.shape=[3,6]: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but
are 6 and 3. Shapes are [6] and [3]. for 'ScatterNd_2' (op: 'ScatterNd') with
input shapes: [6,1], [3,6], [2].`

Seems like my `indices` is specifying row indices instead of column indices, and given the way that arrays are "connected" in numpy and tensorflow (i.e. row-major order), does that mean
I need to *explicitly* specify every single pair of indices for every element in `updates1`?
Or is there some kind of 'wildcard' specification I can use for the rows? (Note `indices1 = tf.constant([[:,0], [:,1], [:,3], [:,4], [:,6], [:,7]])` gives syntax errors, as it probably should.)

Would it be easier to just do a transpose, interleave the rows, then transpose back?
Because I tried that...

```
scatter1 = tf.scatter_nd(indices1, tf.transpose(updates1), tf.transpose(shape))
print(sess.run(tf.transpose(scatter1)))
```

...and got a *much* longer error message, that I don't feel like posting unless someone requests it.

PS- I searched to make sure this isn't a duplicate -- I find it hard to imagine that someone else hasn't asked this before -- but turned up nothing.

Comment: Ok, the following lines actually work, but I have no idea why...     `shape = tf.constant([9, 3])`,
   `scatter1 = tf.transpose(tf.scatter_nd(indices1, tf.transpose(updates1), tf.transpose(shape)))`  ...Particularly strange that I have to define shape as [9,3] and take its transpose, whereas just defining it as [3,9] and using it that way gives an error.

Comment: I would have thought I need to use a shape of [9,3] if I'm using the traspose, or else define [3,9] and then take its transpose. ?  ...So, while I now have 'working code', I'd rather not 'answer my own question': If you can either explain why this is necessary, or offer a better way to do what I want to do, then the prize is yours! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure slicing but I didn't know that syntax like `arr1[0:,:][:,:2]` actually works. It seems it does but not sure if it is better.

This may be the *wildcard* slicing mechanism you are looking for.

```
arr1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,7],[1,2,3,4,5,8]])
arr2 = tf.constant([[10, 11, 12], [10, 11, 12], [10, 11, 12]])

with tf.Session() as sess :
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    print(sess.run(tf.concat([arr1[0:,:][:,:2], arr2[0:,:] [:,:1],
                              arr1[0:,:][:,2:4],arr2[0:, :][:, 1:2],
                              arr1[0:,:][:,4:6],arr2[0:, :][:, 2:3]],axis=1)))
```

Output is

```
[[ 1  2 10  3  4 11  5  6 12]
 [ 1  2 10  3  4 11  5  7 12]
 [ 1  2 10  3  4 11  5  8 12]]
```

So, for example,

`arr1[0:,:]` returns

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [1 2 3 4 5 7]
 [1 2 3 4 5 8]]
```

and `arr1[0:,:][:,:2]` returns the first two columns

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

axis is 1.

Comment: Thanks! I was using scatter_nd instead of concatenate because I need the solution to scale up to hundreds of columns, which I can't count on being able to specify "by hand".  Still, if there's a way to make this "scale", i.e. programatically specifying the columns (without a hundred concat operations which would be slow), then this answer wins.  I also hit upon a different (non-scatter_nd) answer using permutation matrices, which I'll post in a bit...

Answer (score 1):

Some moderators might have regarded my question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207554/swapping-elements-within-a-matrix-rows-and-columns-tensorflow-scatter-nd), not because the questions are the same, but only because the answers contain parts one can use to answer this question -- i.e. specifying every index combination by hand.

A totally different method would be to multiply by a permutation matrix as shown in [the last answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265229/rearrange-columns-of-numpy-2d-array).  Since my original question was about scatter_nd, I'm going to post this solution but wait to see what other answers come in... (Alternatively, I or someone could edit the question to make it about reordering columns, not specific to scatter_nd **--EDIT: I have just edited the question title to reflect this**).

Here, we concatenate the two different arrays/tensors...

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

# the ultimate application is for merging variables which should be in groups,
#   e.g. in this example, [1,2,10] is a group of 3, and there are 3 groups of 3
n_groups = 3
vars_per_group = 3    # once the single value from arr2 (below) is included

arr1 = 10+tf.range(n_groups, dtype=float)
arr1 = tf.stack((arr1,arr1,arr1),0)
arr2 = 1+tf.range(n_groups * (vars_per_group-1), dtype=float)
arr2 = tf.stack((arr2,arr2,arr2),0)

catted = tf.concat((arr1,arr2),1)        # concatenate the two arrays together
print("arr1 = \n",sess.run(arr1))
print("arr2 = \n",sess.run(arr2))
print("catted = \n",sess.run(catted))
```

Which gives output

```
arr1 = 
 [[10. 11. 12.]
 [10. 11. 12.]
 [10. 11. 12.]]
arr2 = 
 [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]]
catted = 
 [[10. 11. 12.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [10. 11. 12.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [10. 11. 12.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]]
```

Now we build the permutation matrix and multiply...

```
start_index = 2               # location of where the interleaving begins

# cml = "column map list" is the list of where each column will get mapped to
cml = [start_index + x*(vars_per_group) for x in range(n_groups)]  # first array  
for i in range(n_groups):                                       # second array 
    cml += [x + i*(vars_per_group) for x in range(start_index)] # vars before start_index
    cml += [1 + x + i*(vars_per_group) + start_index \
        for x in range(vars_per_group-start_index-1)]           # vars after start_index
print("\n cml = ",cml,"\n")

# Create a permutation matrix using p
np_perm_mat = np.zeros((len(cml), len(cml)))
for idx, i in enumerate(cml):
    np_perm_mat[idx, i] = 1
perm_mat = tf.constant(np_perm_mat,dtype=float)

result = tf.matmul(catted, perm_mat)
print("result = \n",sess.run(result))
```

Which gives output

```
cml =  [2, 5, 8, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7] 

result = 
 [[ 1.  2. 10.  3.  4. 11.  5.  6. 12.]
 [ 1.  2. 10.  3.  4. 11.  5.  6. 12.]
 [ 1.  2. 10.  3.  4. 11.  5.  6. 12.]]
```

Even though this doesn't use scatter_nd as the original question asked, one thing I like about this is, you can allocate the `perm_mat` once in some `__init__()` method, and hang on to it, and after that initial overhead it's just matrix-matrix multiplication by a sparse, constant matrix, which should be pretty fast. (?)

Still happy to wait and see what other answers might come in.